# Visual Studio Attach to Process - change default automatic code type (Silverlight instead of Script)

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, internet-explorer, visual-studio-debugging

I'm attaching Visual Studio Debugger to IE instance which is running silverlight application, using Attach to Process dialog.

In the list of available processes there are Script, Silverlight and x86 types listed for iexplore.exe, but Script code gets chosen automatically. Can this be changed? I want Silverlight to be preferred.

Of course I can click Select button and pick Silverlight, but next time I'll need to attach to IIS and change these options again..

Comment: Given that IE is a Javascript enabled browser first and a Silverlight hosting environment second, it makes sense that the default is Script. Given the attach dialog is a bit old (has not changed in years), I guess Microsoft did not feel it was worth being able to configure the defaults. If there is an order it is probably just alphabetized (and Sc comes before Si).

Answer (score 0):

I made a macro to do this.  It would find the iexplore.exe process that was Silverlight whose parent was an iexplore.exe process with a title that matched my application and then attach with silverlight.  One-button attachment!

But then Microsoft removed macro support from Visual Studio 2012.  Grrrr...

I need to re-write it as an extension.