# Cannot debug Silverlight application running through VS 2010

Tags: silverlight

I have an start up page called Default.aspx . Have written an javscript function inside the Head tag which opens an other aspx page and closes this page . The other aspx page of  mine has  silverlight object/ content render on that page . Due to this my debugger doesnt gets attached to the running silverlight application , also when i go to manually attach to the running Silverlight Application it doesnt works , i saw that type of process shown is script / silverlight / x86.

I am doing this all as  my login page is only created in silverlight .

> Any one have idea how can i get debugger atached.

**Edit  :**

Below link explains the same what i am facing :
[Visual Studio Attach to Process - change default automatic code type (Silverlight instead of Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485723/visual-studio-attach-to-process-change-default-automatic-code-type-silverligh)

Answer (score 7):

To enable Silverlight debugging:

- Right click on the Web project hosting the Silverlight application in Solution Explorer
- Select "Properties"
- Click the "Web" tab
- Check the "Silverlight" box in the "Debuggers" section

I had problems debugging Silverlight in Chrome, while in IE it worked like a charm

Comment: I have already done this ~ And i have also said that the running silverlight process type it shows as script, silverlight , x86 .

Comment: the key is to set IE as default browser and not copy/past the link, just let VS open the browser

Answer (score 1):

A very nice utility is the WoVS Default Browser Switcher which can be installed using the Extension Manager (Tools | Extension Manager...)

This tool allows you to set the default browser to be used when debugging your project. In my experience Visual Studio only connects well to IE.

Using the tool I can keep another browser as my default browser but use IE for debugging.

Comment: Note that in Visual Studio 2013 this is a standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

Just use IE as default browser.
It doesn't work properly until you check silver-light debug checkbox and use IE as the others told.
By the way set web application as start-up project.